# Python (Pytorch) - Looping and logging

Tags: python, loops, logging, pytorch

I am very new to Python and would need some help on looping ANN with different number of epoch.

The code starts with

```
import sys
from tqdm import tqdm
import numpy as np

import torch
import torch.nn.functional as F

try:
```

and the epoch part

```
for t in range(2000):
prediction = net(x)
```

May I ask what should I add (before and after the current code) in order to loop the programme for 3 times, then add 1000 epoch and run again till epoch reaches 10000?

Thanks very much.

Also, I would like to know after looping, how to keep the log of the results?

```
loss_func = torch.nn.MSELoss()
```

Comment: please explain a bit more, do you want to run your programme for 10000 epochs?

Comment: Yes. from 2000 to 10000. adding 1000 epochs each time

Comment: then update your for loop as `for t in range(2000, 10000, 1000):`

Answer (score 0):

Update your for loop as:

```
import sys

# To log your outputs in a separate file "myErrorLog.txt"
sys.stdout = open("myErrorLog.txt", "w")
for t in range(2000, 10000, 1000):
    print ("iteration {}".format(t))
    # your work here

# end of your code
sys.stdout.close()
```